# BT2010 - Published Orchestration as WebService - creates solution with no project

Tags: biztalk, publishing, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I ran the wizard to create an .asmx web service from my BizTalk 2010 orchestration.  It ran and created a solution in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myproject directory on disk.  It created a .sln file and under App_Code it created a couple of .cs files.  But there is no .csproj file.  When I open the .sln file it says: "One or more projects were not loaded correctly.  Please see the Output Window for details."

The output window says:

```
http://localhost/AppName_Proxy : error  : Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost/AppName_Proxy'.  The Web site 'http://localhost/AppName_Proxy' does not exist.
```

I'm working on getting the app to open in IE browser as well; Not sure why .sln wouldn't load because of this, but I consider that a separate issue.

My question is why isn't there a .csproj file in the solution?

Answer (score 0):

With .asmx projects the website itself takes the place of the .csproj. 
The problem was that SharePoint was on the machine, and it takes over Port 80. A co-worker had created a "Service Website" for our BizTalk services that runs on Port 9000.

So I edited the .sln file to add the port 9000 as shown below..

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "http://localhost:9000/AppName_Proxy/", "http://localhost:9000/AppName_Proxy", "{D147E9B1-6794-424F-B187-F3262F5A4D07}"
EndProject
... remainder of .sln file not included here.
```

Earlier today I had tried putting the website under Sharepoint, and unblocking .asmx, but other issues beyond scope of this question.